# Plot two columns of data with different number of data points

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, graph

[image]Hi, I have two columns of data. They are over the same time period but column one generates data every 1000ms, and column 2 generates data every 500ms. How can i plot them on the same graph looking of equal length. The x-axis doesnt have to be "Time". Thank you.

```
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [40,20]

x = df['Time']

y1 = df['Engine RPM']
y2 = df['FMS RPM']

plt.plot(x,y1,color='r', label='column1',linewidth=2)
plt.plot(x,y2,color='b', label='column2',linewidth=2)
```

I can have both lines looking equal using the following code, but on seperate graphs.

```
x = np.linspace(0, 100,100)
x2 = np.linspace(0,200,200)

f, ((ax1, ax2)) = plt.subplots(2)

y1 = df['Engine RPM']
y2 = df1['FMS RPM']

ax1.plot(x,y1, label = 'column1') 
ax2.plot(x2,y2, label = 'column2')
```

[image]

Comment: What does your `df['Time']` look like? Better yet, provide the head of the three columns here.

Comment: Hi, its a timestamp, like this 10:35:14

Comment: Hi @QuangHoang, that returned an error module 'pandas' has no attribute 'to_dataframe'

Comment: I mean: `pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])`. Sorry

Comment: Hi @QuangHoang, thanks for reply. That just produced the same graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x = np.linspace(0, 100,100)
x2 = np.linspace(0,200,200)

f, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()

ax.plot(x,y1,color='r', label='column1',linewidth=2)
ax2.plot(x,y2,color='b', label='column2',linewidth=2)
```

Comment: Hi Quang  it worked. I just changed ax1.twiny() to ax.twiny(),   and x,y2  to x2,y2. Thank you for your help.